# Dual/Triple Booting without BootMGR/GRUB/others using PHYSICAL HDD's

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, bios, grub

For starters I have looked over [EFI Boot: Two independently bootable physical hard drives?](https://superuser.com/questions/699189/efi-boot-two-independently-bootable-physical-hard-drives) but TBH it's a little complicated for me, maybe just because I'm unfamiliar with the terminology. All I know is that I am using BIOS:

IBS    Callback_BootEnvironmentDetect: Detected boot environment: BIOS

Also I know 100% I can physically swap PHYSICAL HDD's and "dual boot" because I attempted it on my legacy pc; just curious about having multiple HDD's in my pc and using BIOS to switch/select which HDD to boot from..

Basic question; just wanted to ask if I changed the boot order from BIOS would that be enough to avoid the whole concept of a boot loader? i.e. didn't have to worry about partitions or boot/active flags or physically swapping HDD's.. Looking for an easy way to have multiple OS's w/o messing with a bootloader or boot/active flags; definitely using physical HDD's and not getting into primary/extended/logical partitions, though I am familiar with the differences I still wanted to have them on completely different PHYSICAL drives. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using BIOS instead of EFI, you *might* be able to use the BIOS's boot menu to select your operating system as long as you have each OS installed on its own separate, physical drive.  Please note, however, that the PC BIOS spec is only very loosely defined, and this is a very non-standard config, so if you have a poorly-written BIOS it may not be possible to do this the way you want.

The way the BIOS boots is this:  The hard drive's master boot record (MBR, sector 0) has a partition table which can hold only up to 4 entries; 4 primary partitions, or 3 primaries and a logical (which can be further subdivided into logical drive letters). One, and only one of those partitions (per drive) MUST be marked as active, and it must be one of the primaries (you cannot boot from a logical partition).  When you select a drive from the BIOS boot menu, it is whichever partition that is marked active on that drive that gets booted from.  This is all just FYI in case each drive has multiple partitions on it.  Just know that each drive must have an active partition on it in order to boot.

Now, assuming you're doing a fresh build here, I would install Windows first.  Microsoft just throws boot loaders around willy-nilly and you don't get much say in the matter.

When it comes to Linux, each distro has its own install method, but at some point during the setup you should be asked where you want to put the boot loader, and you generally have three choices: the MBR of the first hard drive, the MBR of the drive you installed Linux to, or the boot record of the partition where you installed Linux.  Go with the last option.  That will prevent Linux from even touching the MBRs of your hard drives.

This *should* be all you need.  If your BIOS is well-behaved, you should be able to boot whichever drive you want at will.