# How do I boot from a partition on my internal HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, boot, partitioning, ssd, multi-boot

I know that there is a solution to my problem, but I just don't seem to get it.

Here's my setup: I've got a laptop with Win10. It has an SSD (where Win10 is stored), and an HDD, which I use for storing data. I want to dual-boot from a partition at my HDD.

Here's the partition scheme of my HDD:

total size: 931GiB

- partition 1 776GiB (Page File, Primary) [used for storing data]
- partition 2 100MiB (EFI System Partition)
- partition 3 72GiB (Primary) [used for storing data]
- 70GiB Free Space
- partition 4 14GiB (Page File, OEM Partition) [recovery]

When I try to boot from my HDD, it says "no bootable device". So, how can I boot from a certain partition in stead of "from my HDD" (do I need to do something with the EFI partition???).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up bootable flag on these partitions you want to boot from. You can do that either from Linux (fdisk/cfdisk) or from Windows (diskmgmt.msc).

The partitions bootable flag is located in partition table, which is the first sector of the drive. Be sure that you have functioning system on these partitions (boot partition for Windows and GRUB for Linux).

Comment: The laptop is an EFI system, which works differently. There is no bootable flag in the partition table, and the partition table is not in the first sector of the drive. See [Rod Smith's answer to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/699189/efi-boot-two-independently-bootable-physical-hard-drives).

Comment: @JohanMyréen lannis didn't stated if it is EFI computer. Disk has EFI partition and it could be the problem. In the end, he would need to reinstall Windows formatting the disk with standard MBR.